# "Заставить" работать в нативных браузерах изображение в base64

Tags: android, ios, изображения, base64, браузер

Есть определенное приложение реализовано в виде `SPA`. После тестирования было замечено, что идет большое количество запросов из-за мелких изображений.

Так как изображения динамические, в спрайты их добавлять нет смысла. Было принято решение в `json` передавать не ссылку на иконку, а саму иконку (иконки у каждого поста уникальные) в `base64`. Однако как выяснилось изображения переданные в `base64` на телефоне не интерпретируются.

Есть ли способ заставить работать изображение в мобильных телефонах?

Comment: Дело в том, что base64 - один из немногих способов преобазовать данные в картинку. Если не работает base64  - то и не работает canvas и т п. Поэтому.... самый простой путь, в onerror написать обработчик, который будет делать `image.src='http://base64handler=base64code'` редирект base64 кода на сервер, а сервер будет с  base64  составлять и отдавать клиенту (браузеру) "картинку".

Comment: Как вариант2 - Можно замутить js который составит точки с цветных div, возможно до 8х8 или 16х16 такой костыль прокатит (если изображение без компрессии, компрессия - дополнительный вопрос).

Comment: @nick_n_a. Сanvas вроде как работает( не буду утверждать). Но цель перевода изображения в строку как раз из-за количество запросов на сервер

Comment: `<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAgACAIABAP8AADikxCwAAAAAAgACAAACAoRRADs=" />` — эта гифка с красным пикселем отлично интерпретируется и фаерфоксом, и хромом, и на компьютере, и на телефоне. Так что непонятно, какие у вас проблемы возникли

Comment: Какой формат изображения используется? Может вы случайно зацепили новый формат с vp6-сжатием, или новые jpeg 2000

Comment: @andreymal, пытаюсь передать изображение в формате jpg. В Mozilla FireFox на талефоне и на компьютере работает все нормально. Вопрос только в нативных браузерах

Comment: @nick_n_a, обычный jpg

Comment: @Node_pro что такое нативные браузеры? В последних андроидах в качестве браузера по умолчанию давным-давно стоит сборка хрома

Comment: Если Canvas работает, можно вывести изображение через Canvas, но... с реализацией jpg кодека на js... будет сложно, и не знаю рационально ли это вообще. gif легко расжать. jpg - там большая сложность. С jpg максимум - это "миниатюру" легко считать т.к. она без сжатия (если она есть, 99% не вшивают миниатюру).

Comment: andreymal,например на айфоне (10 версия) самый последние обновление

Comment: @nick_n_a айфон у меня куда-то потерялся, однако я вам не очень верю, потому что там стоит вполне современный браузер Safari, который просто обязан поддерживать всё это дело

Comment: Попробуйте заменить base64-jpg на base64-png base64-gif или на формат base64-webp. Возможно их найтивный поддерживает. Почитайте какие ещё форматы оно поддерживает. BMP (без сжатия) и GIF (несложное сжатие) - это единственные несложные форматы для которых реально написать декодер в пиксели.